# iframe height for values lower than 150px

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I want to change the iframe height based on how the iframe content changes, but I'm having problems if the iframe's content has a height value lower than 150px.

I've tested this code in Firefox and Chrome and it has the same result.
Here you can test it https://jsfiddle.net/bqvc0pp5/17/

From what I've seen if no height is specified the iframe will automatically have 150px(without border).
In this example I increased the value to 300px then lowered to 200px than to 50px . Everything works great until the 50px is converted to 150px;

```
    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.setAttribute("scrolling","no");

    iframe.onload = () => {
      builtElement();
    };

    //append iframe to main document
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);

    var k=0;


    function builtElement(){
        var div = document.createElement('div');
      div.style.height="50px";
      div.style.backgroundColor="salmon";
      iframe.contentWindow.document.body.style.margin="0px";
      iframe.contentWindow.document.body.appendChild(div);

      div.addEventListener("click", () =>{
            if(k==0){
            div.style.height="300px";
          }
          if(k==1){
            div.style.height="200px";
          }
          if(k==2){
            div.style.height="50px";
          }
          if(k>=2) k=0;
          else k++;
          updateIframeHeight();
      });
    }


    function updateIframeHeight(){
        //I need to reset height or else scrollHeight will be the last max value
      iframe.style.height="";
        var height = iframe.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
      //this is a dirty hack where I can check if offsetHeight is lower than 150px
      var offsetHeight = iframe.contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight;
      //if(offsetHeight<150) height=offsetHeight;
      console.log("scrollHeight: "+height);
      console.log("scrollHeight: "+offsetHeight);
      iframe.style.height=height+"px";
    }
```

If I do a little hack and check if the `offsetHeight` is lower than 150px it works.

```
  var offsetHeight = iframe.contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight;
  if(offsetHeight<150) height=offsetHeight;
```

Is this the best way to do this?

**UPDATE**: In a real example, the iframe body contains more than one elements, but only certain elements change height, therefor changing the body scrollHeight

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution. All you have to do is set the size to 0px;

```
iframe.style.height="0px";
```

What I did previously `iframe.style.height="";` set the height to 150px by default. It appears that if no size is specified the iframe size will be 150px;

Answer (score 0):

this is not the final solution but this may help you to fix your issue without hacks:

```
[Fiddle][1]https://jsfiddle.net/Marouen/qskpdn8b/
```

Comment: thanks, but this is not what I'm looking for. In my real example the body contains more then one div, and I want to be able to calculate body scrollHeight when only one div changes height.

Comment: Ok but this was not the questipn you posted first! Hope you'll find soon a solution

Comment: thanks. I've updated the main post to avoid confusions